# Get Output of lookup activity in a file

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to run a query using lookup activity and store the output in file so that I can use that in mapping data flow. I don't want to use stored procedure option in lookup for this.

Comment: do you mean you want to set the lookup output as the data flow source dataset? And which source do you set in Lookup active, SQL database?

Comment: Yes, I want lookup out as source dataset of Data flow and source of lookup activity is SQL database.

Comment: Your lookup activity will return  one row or several rows?

Comment: It will return one row

Comment: Hi @Kriti, please ref the details in my answer. If it is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use Lookup activity?
You can use Copy activity wherein the source is SQL and you can provide your own query and destination is a blob storage which would generate the file.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nandan's answer, since your source dataset is SQL database, no matter in Lookup active or Data Flow Source, they support the [query option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#azure-sql-database-as-the-source).
[image]

You can run the query which join with many tables like in SSMS, ref the [limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#source-transformation).

If you still want to use Lookup + Data Flow to build your pipeline, you need a variable to accept the Lookup output, then pass the variable to Data Follow parameter:
[image]

Again, If the Lookup and Data Flow have the same source(Database), we all suggest you use only one, it will help save cost.

HTH.