# How to send activity output as email attachment in logic app

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline, I want to send the output of my activity as an email attachment in the logic app.

I have a lookup activity followed by a For each activity and an Inside For each activity I have a web activity to call the logic app.

I want to send the output of the lookup activity as an email attachment to the logic app. I am not able to think about this integration part.

Answer (score 0):

Create Logic app event trigger with HTTP and Outlook.

[image]

> Inside **HTTP  request is received**:

[image]

1. Copy HTTP POST URL
2. Request Body JSON Schema

   `{ "properties": { "dataFactoryName": { "type": "string" }, "message": { "type": "string" }, "pipelineName": { "type": "string" }, "receiver": { "type": "string" } }, "type": "object" }`
3. POST Method

> **Send an Email**

[image]

4. Connect Your outlook email .
5. Use HTTP POST URL as shown in step1

[image]

Create parameter name **receiver**

[image]

6. Add dynamic this content

s

```
{

"message" : "This is the row from lookup item @{item().customerID},@{item().gender},@{item().SeniorCitizen},@{item().Partner}.",

"dataFactoryName" : "@{pipeline().DataFactory}",

"pipelineName" : "@{pipeline().Pipeline}",

"receiver" : "@{pipeline().parameters.receiver}"

}
```

[image]

**Pipeline successfully executed and got the output:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct or easy way to send email attachment from ADF.

But as a workaround first you will have to save the output of your lookup activity to a file and then follow the approach described in this video by a community volunteer where logic apps come into play to send the lookup activity output data file as an attachment. [How To Send File as Attachment From Azure Data Factory - Azure Data Factory Tutorial 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNJhhT0DDMM)

In order to save the lookup output data to a file you can follow this approach: [Get Output of lookup activity in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66024162/get-output-of-lookup-activity-in-a-file)